# Put iframe in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, popup

I was planning on putting youtube(website) in an iframe and then put my own content in another iframe, so two iframe in one window, one with youtube and the other with my own content.

however I found out that youtube does not display in an iframe. So in order to solve my problem I thought of putting youtube in a (popup)window and in the same window putting an iframe with my content. I googled for this but I couldn't find anything about putting iframe in (popup)windows. Can this be done?

Comment: You will not have access to the document if you load a third party website in a popup window. This is obviously in the interest of security.

Comment: Whether it's a popup or not it doesn't matter, they're both windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot do this.**

A popup window opens a webpage.

=> If you will open your own page in that popup, youtube will have to be in iframe, so not possible.

=> If you open youtube.com in popup, then you cannot access that page.(Its youtube.com in another window) . So, not possible again.

So, I recommend you to use youtube api's . They are simply great and offer alot.

[Youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started)

Comment: Thanks:) (I will no longer waste my time on this..)